# Duplicated value in my JSON response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I created method `show()` in controller to return name and timestamps + all permissions this role has. Spatie/Laravel-Permission is responsible for associating users with permissions and roles in my API.

```php
    public function show($name)
    {
        $role = Role::findByName($name);
        return response()->json([
            $role,
            $role->permissions
        ]);
    }
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "root",
        "created_at": "2019-04-08 19:41:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-08 19:41:49",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "name": "users.store"
            },
            {
                "name": "users.destroy"
            },
            {
                "name": "users.show.id"
            },
            {
                "name": "users.update.id"
            },
            {
                "name": "users.show.name"
            },
            {
                "name": "users.update.name"
            }
        ]
    },
    [
        // This is duplicate
        {
            "name": "users.store"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.destroy"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.show.id"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.update.id"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.show.name"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.update.name"
        }
    ]
]
```

As you can see there is useless duplicate of permissions.

But if I will remove $role from my response

```php
        return response()->json([
//            $role,
            $role->permissions
        ]);
```

Everything is fine

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "users.store"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.destroy"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.show.id"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.update.id"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.show.name"
        },
        {
            "name": "users.update.name"
        }
    ]
]
```

And when I want to return only $role without permissions like this:

```php
        return response()->json([
            $role,
//            $role->permissions
        ]);
```

My output is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "root",
        "created_at": "2019-04-08 19:41:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-08 19:41:49"
    }
]
```

Comment: `permissions` is never defined as a property of the `Role` class https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Role.php  It's used only one time [in that class] that I can find `return $this->permissions->contains('id', $permission->id);` at the end of `hasPermissionTo()`  I am not a laravel user so I don't know what `extends Model` has.

Comment: Prolly though some underling code when you do `$role->permissions` it populates the value (lazy loading etc...), you can try calling that before doing the `json` stuff.  `$role->permissions; return response()->json([$role]);`  To check that theory out, because if it's correct then it should be populated in this case, where it wasn't previously (without calling `$role->permissions`). That said there may be ways to eagerly load this etc... that are more sound ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is no property like ```permissions``` of Role model, but of something else (Unfortunately I don't have time to investigate :) ). I found other correct way how to achieve my expected result: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/876 Thank you for help

Comment: `$role->load('permissions');` eager loading.  This is probably the correct way to do it.  I just don't know Eloquent ( but I have build ORMs, so I know what they do, how they do it) and used things like Doctrine (with some frustration, works fine tell you get a few million rows... lol) etc....

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$role->permissions` in your response, permissions are loaded into the `$role` object, and then serialized to json. So basically you're sending `$role` object with loaded permissions, and you're also sending permissions themselves.

Try:

```php
public function show($name)
{
    $role = Role::findByName($name)->load('permissions');

    return response()->json([
        $role
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Eloquent: API Resources [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction)

```
public function show($name)
{
    return new RoleResource(Role::findByName($name));
}
```

and RoleResource like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class RoleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            'permissions' => $this-> permissions,
        ];
    }
}
```